# default credentials in VBA

Tags: vba, proxy, httpclient

I'm tryng to make a HTTP request from VB for Applications ( VBA)
that should have been simple:

```
URL = "https://www.google.com/"
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xhr.Open "GET", URL, False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xhr.Send
MsgBox xhr.responseText
```

BUT I'm behind a proxy server which require basic auth (base64).

How to set the credentials in VBA ?

(something equivalent to : myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials)

If this is not possible, how to solve the issue with another approach ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could adapt this VBScript to VBA: http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=702

Comment: It is a bit late, but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964337/make-a-http-get-request-from-excel-through-a-proxy-with-default-credentials . If the proxy uses the logged on user if the proxy is configured for the internet explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the setProxyCredentials method.  I don't have a proxy to test, but this should do the trick:

```
URL = "https://www.google.com/"
Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xhr.Open "GET", URL, False
xhr.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xhr.setProxy 2, "192.168.0.222:8080"
xhr.setProxyCredentials "your_username" , "password_for_username"
xhr.Send
MsgBox xhr.responseText
```

Taken from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008874/xmlhttp-request-ajax-with-vbskript-does-not-work-with-proxy-connection) which points out the 2 argument is a version number that you may need to change.