# Make a http get Request from Excel through a Proxy with default credentials

Tags: excel, vba, proxy

I want to get data from a Website(just a simple webrequest), from an Excel, the only problem is, the application is behind a proxy and i don't want to hardcode Username and Password.

Is there a way to get the default Proxy and set the credentials from the current User, without hard coding it?

***With other words:** I would like authenticate against the proxy, with the user that is currently logged on the Windows machine.*

This is the relevant code:

```vb
   Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
   URL = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
   objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False

   'If possible i would like to get the default proxysettings
   objHTTP.setProxy 2, "proxy:8282"

   'I dont wont to set this line
   objHTTP.setProxyCredentials "username", "password"
   objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
   objHTTP.send ("")
```

*I googled, but i could find a clear no, or an alternative solution.*

It should run in en Windows environment. Any Help and/or Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What exectly do you mean by "set the credentials from the current User"? IE proxy settings? Credential manager settings? Sg else?

Comment: I would like authenticate against the proxy, with the user that is currently logged on the Windows machine.

Comment: Does the network use [wpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) for the proxy settings?

Comment: Not that I know of. The proxy is/has to be entered in all configuration, not automatic discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find anything better at the moment, but this is a *quick & "dirty"* solution, that works, with "Standard" components(and more over for my secific needs).

Since the proxy is set for the Internet Explorer, for every User

**1) Add a Webbrowser control**

[image]
[image]

**2) Set the properties for the Control**
**Name:** browser, *optional change the size that it wont be visible or so*

[image]

**3) Write this Code into the worksheet, with the browser control**

<! --lang:lang-vb -->

```
Private Sub browser_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    Debug.Print browser.Document.body.innerHTML
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    browser.Navigate "stackoverflow.com"
End Sub
' Tested on Win7 with Excel 2010
```

the Code reacts sometimes a bit flakey(javascript errors, ...), but it uses the Proxy and the logged on User.

> **Update 1:**
>
> for other Scenarios, where the Internet Explorer has no proxy set, this could be down ***(very dirty workaround)*** by setting the proxy with the registry keys:

> ```
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer
> ```
>
> Although for this to work, the application would have to terminate all running IE's and then Start the browser.
>
> > **Disclaimer:** *I didn't try this (it's just an idea i had), since for my >>needs the above solution is enough, and it seems to me very >>radical/dangerous and there could/should be a better way.*

Comment: this is a very specific solution for my environment, since Internet Explorer proxy settings are rolled out, with group policies.