# Proxy Authenticaton VBA - How to not prompt?

Tags: vba, proxy, http-proxy

I track POD's Online. I do it from behind a proxy and use Microsoft Access in a query to execute the function to download the tracking information and parse it out.  The base code is below.  The function I use is TrackNew(trackingNumber).  Each morning when I run this access.exe is asking for my credentials.  I track from UPS and FedEx xml gateways and it doesn't ask for the proxy credentials.  Is there a way that I can add the credentials inside my code so it doesn't prompt for this?
Here at the top is everything that makes this work.  At the bottom is the actual function.

```
Private Enum HTTPequestType
HTTP_GET
HTTP_POST
HTTP_HEAD
End Enum

#If VBA7 Then
' 64-bit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet" 
(ByRef dwflags As LongPtr, _

ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
#Else
' pre 64-bit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState Lib "wininet" 
(ByRef dwflags As Long, _
                                                                ByVal 
dwReserved As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const CONNECT_LAN As Long = &H2
Private Const CONNECT_MODEM As Long = &H1
Private Const CONNECT_PROXY As Long = &H4
Private Const CONNECT_OFFLINE As Long = &H20
Private Const CONNECT_CONFIGURED As Long = &H40

' Application Objects
Private xl As Access.Application

' misc symbols
Private Const CHAR_SPACE As String = " "
Private Const CHAR_UNDERSCORE As String = "_"
Private Const CHAR_COMMA As String = ","
Private Const CHAR_SLASH As String = "/"
Private Const AT_SYMBOL As String = "@"

' list of carriers (must be UPPER CASE, comma-delimited)
Private Const CARRIER_LIST As String = 

"UPS,UPS1,UPS2,UPS3,UPS4,UPS5,UPS6,UPS7,UPS8,NEW,DHL,DHL1,FEDEX,FEDEX2,FEDEX3,FEDEX4,FEDEX5,HOLLAND,CONWAY,ABF,CEVA,USPS,TNT,YRCREGIONAL,YRC,NEMF,A1,RWORLDCOURIER,BLUEDART,TCIXPS,PUROLATOR,EXPINT,CMACGM,SAFM,PLG,DHL,ONTRAC,AAACT,RLC,ODFL,SAIA,DHLGLOBAL,LASERSHIP"

' MSXML stuff
Private Const MSXML_VERSION As String = "6.0"

' error Msgs
Private Const UNKNOWN_CARRIER As String = "Unknown carrier"
Private Const ERROR_MSG As String = "Error"
Private Const PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND As String = "Package Not Found"
Private Const MSIE_ERROR As String = "Cannot start Internet Explorer."
Private Const MSXML_ERROR As String = "Cannot start MSXML 6.0."
Private Const MSHTML_ERROR As String = "Cannot load MSHTML Object library."

' URLs for each carrier
 Private Const NEWUrl As String = "https://www.newpenn.com/embeddable-tracking-results/?track="
 ' 
 ' system functions
 ' 
 Private Function GetAppTitle() As String
 GetAppTitle = App.Title & " " & App.Major & "." & App.Minor & "." & App.Revision
 End Function
 Private Function IsWindowsOS() As Boolean
 ' true if operating system is Windows
 IsWindowsOS = (GetWindowsOS Like "*Win*")
 End Function
 ' 
 ' required addin procedures
 ' 

Private Sub AddinInstance_OnAddInsUpdate(custom() As Variant)
' needed for operation
Exit Sub
End Sub
Private Sub AddinInstance_OnStartupComplete(custom() As Variant)
' needed for operation
Exit Sub
End Sub
' helper functions

Private Function GetRequestType(reqType As HTTPequestType) As String
Select Case reqType
Case 1
GetRequestType = "POST"
Case 2
GetRequestType = "HEAD"
Case Else  ' GET is default
GetRequestType = "GET"
End Select
End Function

Private Function IsValidCarrier(CarrierName As String) As Boolean
' returns TRUE if the given carrier is on the global list
Dim carriers() As String
carriers = Split(CARRIER_LIST, ",")
IsValidCarrier = (UBound(Filter(carriers, CarrierName)) > -1)
End Function

Private Function GetHTMLAnchors(htmlDoc As Object) As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
On Error Resume Next
Set GetHTMLAnchors = htmlDoc.anchors
End Function

Private Function LoadError(xmlDoc As Object) As Boolean
' checks if a xml file load error occurred
LoadError = (xmlDoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0)
End Function

Private Function GetRootNode(xmlDoc As Object) As Object
' returns root node
Set GetRootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
End Function

Private Function GetNode(parentNode As Object, nodeNumber As Long) As Object
On Error Resume Next
' if parentNode is a MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Set GetNode = parentNode.Item(nodeNumber - 1)
' if parentNode is a MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
If GetNode Is Nothing Then
Set GetNode = parentNode.ChildNodes(nodeNumber - 1)
End If
End Function

Private Function CreateFile(fileName As String, contents As String) As String
' creates file from string contents
Dim TempFile As String
Dim nextFileNum As Long
nextFileNum = FreeFile
TempFile = fileName
Open TempFile For Output As #nextFileNum
Print #nextFileNum, contents
Close #nextFileNum
CreateFile = TempFile
End Function
```

Here is where it prompts me for the windows domain credentials for the proxy.

```
Private Function GetResponse(xml As Object, requestType As HTTPequestType, _
                         destinationURL As String, Optional async As Boolean, _
                         Optional requestHeaders As Variant, Optional postContent As String) As String

Dim reqType As String
Dim response As String
Dim i As Long

reqType = GetRequestType(requestType)

With xml
.Open reqType, destinationURL, async

' check for headers
If Not IsMissing(requestHeaders) Then
For i = LBound(requestHeaders) To UBound(requestHeaders)
.setRequestHeader requestHeaders(i, 1), requestHeaders(i, 2)
Next i
End If

' if HTTP POST, need to send contents
' will not harm GET or HEAD requests
.Send (postContent)

' if HEAD request, return headers, not response
If reqType = "HEAD" Then
  response = xml.getAllResponseHeaders
Else
response = xml.responseText
End If
End With

GetResponse = response
End Function

Private Function GetRequestHeaders() As Variant
Dim tempArray(1 To 1, 1 To 2) As Variant

tempArray(1, 1) = "Content-Type"
tempArray(1, 2) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

GetRequestHeaders = tempArray
End Function

' major objects

Private Function GetMSIE() As Object  ' InternetExplorer.Application
On Error Resume Next
Set GetMSIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
End Function

Private Function CreateHTMLDoc() As Object  ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
On Error Resume Next
Set CreateHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
End Function

Private Function GetMSXML() As Object  ' MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
On Error Resume Next
Set GetMSXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP" & IIf(Len(MSXML_VERSION) = 0, "", "." & MSXML_VERSION))
End Function

Private Function GetServerMSXML() As Object
On Error Resume Next
Set GetServerMSXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" & 
IIf(Len(MSXML_VERSION) = 0, "", "." & MSXML_VERSION))
End Function

Private Function CreateXMLDoc() As Object  ' MSXML2.DOMDocument60
On Error Resume Next
Set CreateXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument" & IIf(Len(MSXML_VERSION) = 0, "", "." & MSXML_VERSION))
End Function

' XMLHTTP or MSIE

'''''Private Function GetMSXMLWebResponse(URL As String) As String
'''''  Dim webObject As Object  ' MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
'''''  Set webObject = GetMSXML
'''''  If webObject Is Nothing Then  ' cannot start MSXML6
'''''    Exit Function
'''''  End If
'''''  ' open URL and scrape result
'''''  With webObject
'''''    .Open "GET", URL, False
'''''    .send
'''''  End With
'''''  GetMSXMLWebResponse = webObject.responseText
'''''End Function

Private Function GetMSIEWebResponse(URL As String) As String
Dim webObject As Object  ' InternetExplorer.Application
Set webObject = GetMSIE
If webObject Is Nothing Then  ' cannot start MSIE
Exit Function
End If
'open the url
webObject.navigate URL
'wait for the site to be ready
Do Until webObject.readyState = 4  ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
'read the text from the body of the site
GetMSIEWebResponse = webObject.Document.body.innerText
webObject.Quit
End Function
```

Here is the actual tracking code:

```
Private Function TrackNEW(trackingNumber As String) As String
Dim xml As Object
Dim tempString As String
Dim htmlDoc As Object  ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlBody As Object  ' MSHTML.htmlBody
Dim anchors As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim anchor As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim dda As Object  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim ddb As Object
Dim ddc As Object
Dim ddd As Object
Dim span As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim class As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Set xml = GetMSXML
If xml Is Nothing Then  ' cannot start MSXML 6.0
TrackNEW = MSXML_ERROR
Exit Function
End If

tempString = GetResponse(xml, HTTP_GET, NEWUrl & trackingNumber, False)

If Len(tempString) = 0 Then
MsgBox "5"
TrackNEW = ERROR_MSG
Exit Function
End If

Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
If htmlDoc Is Nothing Then ' cannot reference MSHTML object library
MsgBox "6"
TrackNEW = MSHTML_ERROR
Exit Function
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body
htmlBody.innerHTML = tempString

Set dda = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Set ddb = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Set ddc = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
Set ddd = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
Item = 1
For Each Strg4 In ddd
For ItemNumber4 = 400 To 450
Strg4 = ddd.Item(ItemNumber4).innerText
    If InStr(Strg4, "Projected Delivery Date") >= 1 Then
    Why = ItemNumber4
    Strg4 = ddd.Item(Why).innerText
    GoTo Line8
    Else
    End If
Next ItemNumber4
Next Strg4
GoTo Line9
Exit Function
Line8:
TrackNEW = "INTRANSIT" & "|" & Right(Strg4, 11)
Exit Function
Line9:
Item = 1
For Each Strg In dda
For ItemNumber = 160 To 200
Strg = dda.Item(ItemNumber).innerText
    If InStr(Strg, "DELIVERED") >= 1 Then
    That = ItemNumber
    Strg = dda.Item(That).innerText
    GoTo Line2
    Else
    End If
Next ItemNumber
Next Strg
GoTo Line1
Line2:
Item2 = 1
For Each Strg2 In ddb
For ItemNumber2 = 160 To 200
Strg2 = ddb.Item(ItemNumber2).innerText
     If InStr(Strg2, "DELIVERED") >= 1 Then
     This = ItemNumber2 + 3
     Strg2 = ddb.Item(This).innerText
     GoTo Line3
     Else
     End If
     Next ItemNumber2
     Next Strg2
     GoTo Line1
Line3:
Item3 = 1
For Each Strg3 In ddb
For ItemNumber3 = 160 To 200
Strg3 = ddb.Item(ItemNumber3).innerText
     If InStr(Strg3, "DELIVERED") >= 1 Then
     How = ItemNumber3 + 5
     Strg3 = ddc.Item(How).innerText
     GoTo Line4
     Else
     End If
     Next ItemNumber3
     Next Strg3
     GoTo Line1
Line4:
TrackNEW = Strg & "|" & Strg2 & "|" & Strg3
Set xml = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing  ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set htmlBody = Nothing  ' MSHTML.htmlBody
Set anchors = Nothing  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set anchor = Nothing  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set dda = Nothing
Exit Function
Line1:
TrackNEW = "TRACKING|CANNOT|BE|FOUND"
Set xml = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing  ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set htmlBody = Nothing  ' MSHTML.htmlBody
Set anchors = Nothing  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Set anchor = Nothing  ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Set dda = Nothing
Exit Function
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I need the actual lines of code or reference that would get around it from prompting me for the windows credentials the proxy.

I found this snippet of code.  Under the GETMSXML i could add this?

```
'Set GetMSXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" & IIf(Len(MSXML_VERSION) = 0, "", "." & MSXML_VERSION))
'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 'GetMSXML.setProxy 2, "proxy.website.com:8080"
 'GetMSXML.setProxyCredentials "user", "password"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015014/default-credentials-in-vba

Comment: Your edit broadly matches the link I gave above. Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: @QHarr Yes.  I tried that and it is working fine now.  I use it for the webpage download and xml gateways of fedex, dhl and purolater now.  The proxy no longer prompts me anymore.  I appreciate the help.